# fig.axes returns more axes than I have initiated. (python matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am initiating ax1, and making several axes by ax1.twinx(). However, when I create 3 axes, fig.axes output 6 axes objects, and when I create 4 axes, it output 8 objects. Why is that?
My code is below.

```
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        color_lst = ["tab:blue", "tab:orange", "tab:green", "tab:red", "tab:purple", "tab:brown", "tab:pink", "tab:gray", "tab:olive", "tab:cyan"]
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
        
        plt.xlabel("Run number")

        color = color_lst[0]
        ax1.plot(range(len(data_arr[0])), data_arr[0], label = param_names[0], color = color)
        ax1.set_ylabel(param_names[0])
        ax1.yaxis.label.set_color(color)
        ax1.spines["right"].set_edgecolor(color)
        ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=color)

        ax_lst = [ax1.twinx() for i in range(len(data_arr))]

        i=0
        for ax in ax_lst[1:]:
            i+=1
            color = color_lst[i]
            ax = ax1.twinx()
            ax.plot(range(len(data_arr[i])), data_arr[i], label = param_names[i], color = color)
            ax.set_ylabel(param_names[i])

            ax.spines["right"].set_position(("outward", (i-1)*80)) #Setting axis position offset
            #Coloring all parts of the axes
            ax.spines["right"].set_edgecolor(color)
            ax.yaxis.label.set_color(color)
            ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=color)

        print("AX LIST: " + str(fig.axes))
        comp_ax_lst = fig.axes
        comp_ax_lst[1].remove()
```

What led me to ask this question is that I cannot seem to remove the black right y-axis going from 0 to 1 in the following plot, which is made using the code above.
[Figure with weird black right yaxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAaPR.png)

Best regards

Comment: You're already creating the twin axes in your list comprehension i.e. `ax_lst`. Then when you loop through this ax list, you create another twin axes. So, remove `ax=ax1.twinx()` in your loop.

Comment: Wow, I am so sorry that I didn't see that. I thought I had found something about mpl axes that should be brought to light, when it was just me spawning doubles.. (This also fixed the weird axis) Thanks David.